# MS Graph: Upgrading from Adal in .net core 2.0 to Msal in 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I'm looking to upgrade my WebAPI application which calls MS Graph with from Adal in .Net 2.0 to Msal in .net 3.1. My application uses B2C for authorization to the endpoints. I use Adal to call the MS Graph in order to get the groups claims and detect if a user is an admin or not.

I see Adal has reached end of life. I have looked at Msal.Net, but there aren't may examples on how to configure an API in .Net Core 3.1. How do I wire up configuration to both AzureB2C and Azure Active directory? Is there an example that I can follow to query the MS Graph?

I successfully wired up my api to check AzureB2C, how can I query MS Graph?

Comment: Querying the Graph api hasn't changed really, as long as you can obtain a valid token. So does this help you? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-aad-b2c-considerations

Comment: That link looks like it is signing into b2c. I'm just trying to query a user's claims from an admin account in my WebAPI. Yeah, I realize querying as remained the same but Adal which is what I used has been deprecated. Straight off it doesn't look like the link helps, but I appreciate it.

Comment: I just imported the same Active Directory library and it worked. I was wanting to upgrade, but it will do for now.

Comment: I used to find a sample in java to achieve protect web api application in azure ad, and I found a [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/sample-v2-code#web-apis) from here, and it also provides samples in dotnet, pls refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

There are the [differences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-migration#differences-between-adal-and-msal-apps) between ADAL and MSAL apps. ADAL is based on the v1.0 endpoint and MSAL is based on v2.0.

**Code sample**

1. Call Microsoft Graph `/me` endpoint on behalf of the **signed-in user**: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph
2. Use the [client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to acquire an access token which can be used to call the Microsoft Graph: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-v2/tree/master/1-Call-MSGraph